# icon "download" in arduino IDE 2.0.2 don't appear

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide

how to install esp8266 board on arduino IDE 2.0.2? I had done this step (https://wasiswa.com/cara-install-esp-8266-node-mcu-di-arduino-ide-2-0/) but In my arduino IDE does not appear the icon to download. I've tried clicking "more info" which enters the github link then I downloaded the zip file (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino) and put the zip and the extracted results into the arduino folder at C:. And i had added http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json,https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json at my preference> URL.

[image: my esp8266 board option that there's no download icon]
[image: my esp8266 board option that there's no download icon]
[image: the esp8266 board not yet installed]
[image: my esp8266 board that i downloaded from github then i had added to Arduino's folder]

I want to can use esp8266 board in my arduino IDE 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the json library first, to later be able to implement the board in the manager.

[image]